# Kiel vision simulator does not execute store instruction

Tags: assemblies, arm, assembly

When I use the str intruction  ex: STR R1,[r15]
Why does it not store the value into memory?

Comment: Bad example. R15 is the PC (Program counter) which will usually point to read-only memory.

Comment: if i have this example ADR R1,array_1  LDR R2,[R1]  STR R2,[R8]... the store doesnot work... doest store in address found in R8

Answer (score 1):

it could still be in the data cache